# Can't run ubuntu 12.04 problem seems to be video driver, card is via s3 pro savage 4

Tags: drivers, video

I start "Run ubuntu from this USB" and it loads and shows Ubuntu dots screen but when this finish the screen doesn't show welcome screen or anything else and I need to force shutdown with power button

Comment: Seems to be a problem with savage s3 drivers. See my question for a brief on the theme. No solution, at the date. http://askubuntu.com/questions/271426/ubuntu-doesnt-recognize-screen

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution for the S3 Savage MX-MV

At the time of display problem: 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd>, or <kbd>F3</kbd> etc.).
During your session, your screen becomes a console.
Login with your user name and password:

It starts by generating its `xorg.conf.new` which does not exist in Xubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo X-configure
```

Copy to `/etc/X11`:

```
sudo cp /home/$USER/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Install wim editor:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Afterwards, edit the `xorg.conf` file using vim:

```
sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

To insert text, press <kbd>i</kbd>, then <kbd>Esc</kbd> when done.
To delete an entire line, <kbd>dd</kbd> (that is, the <kbd>d</kbd> key twice).
To quit without saving exchange, <kbd>q</kbd>.
To save changes: <kbd>wq</kbd>.

Correct the following in:

```
Section "Device"
         [...]
        Identifier "Card0"
# Comment out or delete the following line
# Driver "modesetting"
# Add the following line
      Driver "vesa"
EndSection
```

Restart BOOT: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>.

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution. But I get stuck at the first step: Ctrl + Alt + F1 -> when I press it, I get a blue pattern printer on the whole screen. Is there any other way I could access the "terminal window" ?
Thanks matej